# apt purge/remove is not freeing up all of the space that it should

Tags: apt, uninstall, disk-usage, purge

I installed the cinnamon desktop with apt and it said it was about 85mb. But when I use `sudo apt remove cinnamon` or `sudo apt purge cinnamon`, the amount of disk space that it says it is freeing up is only 1164kb, about 1mb. Why is there such a discrepancy? There will be so much wasted space on my computer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because Desktop Environments like Cinnamon tend to be a compilation of a lot of different programs, like file managers, terminal emulators, web browsers, etc.

After you use `sudo apt-get remove cinnamon` you need to also use

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

To remove all the packages that are no longer needed.